# Google Cloud / App Engine - add new custom domain not verified on App Engine

Tags: validation, webserver

I need to do server-side tagging in GTM. I have created a project in Google Cloud and I need to add a new custom domain in App Engine - settings. I am following this manual https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/serverside/custom-domain
3rd step

After going through the steps to create a new custom domain, the page still shows "Your domain hasn't been verified yet. Finish all the steps in Webmaster Central and then return to this page."

I followed all the steps and created a TXT record on the domain using the supplied key, but the new domain remains unverified on Google Cloud, with no messages, no contact.

Answer (score 0):

1. When you add the DNS records to your domain name provider, you need to wait for the DNS changes to be propagated. IIRC, the default value for a new DNS record will be 1 hour which means you have to wait for about an hour (can also take as long as  a day). You can also change it from 1 hour to 1 minute, give it a few minutes then try.
2. Separately, you need to make sure you are entering the right data. You can also try a CNAME record if the TXT change doesn't work for you.

Comment: I have no problems with validation. The problem is Google Cloud doesn't see information from Webmaster Central. I have validated the domain by 2 different methods and there is no problem on this side, so there no problem with the data I am entering.

Here some screenshots:
https://monosnap.com/file/3W7DDhPdRF2PrLFaFAFFYZ8dCvwZsI
 https://monosnap.com/file/xMG6hsmvrZqB6LbDUDRyJpH2GskGtH